# Can I use an asynchronous function in a stream.map()?

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, dart, stream

Is it possible to pass an asynchronous function into a stream.map() function?

```
final CollectionReference myCollection =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('foo');


Future<Stream<MyModel>> get myStream async {
    // incorrect code, but I want to do something like this
    return await myCollection.snapshots().map(_mappingFunc);
}

Future<MyModel> _mappingFunc(QuerySnapshot snapshot) async {
    // some async code
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible, since the declaration of the `map` is the following:

```
Stream<S> map <S>(
      S convert(
          T event
        )
     )
```

`map` takes a `convert` function which is of type `S`, basically the type of the `Stream` used.

You can use the `asyncMap()` method:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [asyncMap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html) to perform the mapping which outputs to a `Stream` or you can wrap your function and await the result to use an asynchronous function with List.map to get a `List` result:

```dart
myCollection.snapshots().map((e) async => await _mappingFunc(e));
```

Another option is to use an `async*` method to achieve a `Stream` output:

```dart
Stream<MyModel> get myStream async* {
  for (final snapshot in myCollection.snapshots()) {
    yield await _mappingFunc(snapshot);
  }
}
```